# What is the use of getchar() != in this piece of code?

Tags: getchar

In this little piece of code in don't get what the useof getchar is. 
They ask the user to enter an int value and I have to check if it´s valid or not. I understand status, it should check if there's only 1 value entered.

thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void)
{

    int x;
    int status;
    status = scanf("%i", &x);
    if ((status != 1) || (getchar() != ’\n’)){
    printf("\nUnvalid entry\n");
    return 1;
}
printf("\nValid entry\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It says if input character is not return or new line character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getchar()` in your program ensures that the user enters only one argument. 
`getchar()` asks for the next character from the input.
So if you entered '1','2',[Space],[ENTER]
getchar returns the char `' '`, and in our case it means that we have more than one argument.

Comment: Why is ' ' the last character in the input "1 2"? Shouldn't that be the 2?

Comment: You may want to clearify that in your question. It reads as if you type '1', ' ', '2', '[ENTER]'.

Comment: @Ido: I have edited your answer to improve the English, please check that your are happy with my edits.

Comment: Thank you Martin!

Comment: @BDL: `getchar()` returns the *next* character.  Another example where it would be rejected is if you wrote "1.2<enter>".  The "1" would be accepted, and `getchar` would return the '.'

Comment: @MartinBonner: Sure, I know that. With your edit the answer is now very clear in stating it. I only doubted that the writer of this answer understood it.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` basically checks for the character.

`getchar() != ’\n’` checks that the character is not a newline character.

you can visit https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-getchar-getch-getc-getche/
to get more out of this